# Extract BMP from .EXE file

Tags: c, bmp

I have a code in C with which I can find BMP images. It selects my image well, which has 3992 bytes, for example. I checked this with a Resource Tuner program. How can I save what I saved in the buffer as a BMP file?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

struct BMPHeader
{
    char signature[2];
};

int main()
{
    FILE* file = fopen("C:\\Program Files\\...", "rb");

    if (!file)
    {
        printf("Nu s-a putut deschide fisierul.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    struct BMPHeader* bmpHeaders = NULL;
    int bmpCount = 0;

    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    long fileSize = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

    while (ftell(file) < fileSize)
    {
        struct BMPHeader header;
        fread(&header, sizeof(struct BMPHeader), 1, file);
        if (memcmp(header.signature, "BM", 2) == 0)
        {
            long int poz = ftell(file);
            int fileSizeBMP = 0;
            char buffer[3992];

            fread(&fileSizeBMP, 4, 1, file);
            fseek(file, 0, SEEK_CUR);

            size_t bytesread = fread(&buffer, sizeof(char), fileSizeBMP, file);
            printf("%i ", fileSizeBMP);
            if(fileSizeBMP == 3992)
            {
                for(size_t i=0; i<bytesread; i++)
                {
                    printf("%02x ", buffer[i]);
                }

                FILE* file = fopen("image1.bmp", "wb");

                fwrite(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, file);

                printf("%zu ", bytesread);
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried as it is now but the file is corrupted, I think something is stuck. I'm thinking maybe the header is not complete

Comment: Why are you doing it this way instead of using Win32's built-in functions to extract resources?

Comment: I didn't know about this thing, it's the first time I do it.

Comment: `fseek()`, `ftell()`, `fread()` and `fwrite()` can fail and you should check the return value before you proceed. `printf()` can also fail but there is not that much you should/can do about it, ignoring it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

A BMP file starts with `"BM"` and then it has the file size.  You read that part but don't write it. And a BMP file without that header is corrupted.
It could work with this improvments.

```
....
//no changes here

#define BM_HEADER "BM" //Add to follow DRY in the changed code

void die(const char *msg) //Add this to handle errors
{
    perror(msg); 
    exit(1);
}

int main()
{
    ....
    //No changes at the opening of the file

    int bmpCount = 0;     // Remove this line. You don't use it.

    //Don't need file size, use the return value of fread() to detect
    // the end

    while(1) //use the return value of fread() to determine end of file
    {
        struct BMPHeader header;
        if(fread(&header, sizeof(struct BMPHeader), 1, file)<1)
        { 
            break; //End of file
        }
        if(memcmp(header.signature, BM_HEADER, strlen(BM_HEADER) ) == 0)
        {
            long int poz = ftell(file); //remove this line, you don't use poz
            //use a uint32_t to have the correct size regardless of archidekture
            uint32_t fileSizeBMP = 0;
            char buffer[3992];

            fread(&fileSizeBMP, sizeof fileSizeBMP, 1, file); //use sizeof instead of hardcoded values
            fseek(file, 0, SEEK_CUR); //remove this line, it does basically nothing (position doesn't change)

            //Note, BMP uses little endian integers, your CPU may or may not use little endian
            //Your code will break on a CPU that doesn't use little endian. 

            //a char has always the size of 1.
            size_t bytesread = fread(&buffer, 1, fileSizeBMP, file);
            if(!bytesread) //couldn't read the data
            {
                die("read error");
            }
            //changed type of fileSizeBMP, changed format string accordingly
            printf("%PRIu32\n ", fileSizeBMP);
            if(fileSizeBMP == sizeof buffer ) //use sizeof to follow DRY
            {
                for(size_t i=0; i<fileSizeBMP; i++)
                {
                    printf("%02x ", buffer[i]);
                }

                FILE* fileOut = fopen("image1.bmp", "wb"); //rename file to avoid confusion

                if(fputs(BM_HEADER, fileOut)<0) //You need the header "BM"
                {
                    die("write error");
                }
                if(!fwrite(fileSizeBMP, sizeof(fileSizeBMP), 1, fileOut)) //And the size
                {
                    die("write error");
                }
                if(!fwrite(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, fileOut)) //Don't forget to check for errors
                {
                    die("write error");
                }

                printf("%zu ", bytesread);
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

I am not sure if the `fileSizeBMP` is the complete file size or the size after the `fileSizeBMP`
(Your file is maybe 6 bytes too large).

I wasn't sure what your rule is where to put spaces between `if`/`while`/`for` and `()`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use `fseek(file, 0, SEEK_CUR)` to return to the beginning, read everything to `buffer`, and write `buffer` to file.

The problem is that your `fseek()` call adds 0 to the current position, so nothing changes. The file you write is missing the header, because you read it before the `fseek()` call.

If the file contained just the BMP data, you could simply use `fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET)` to set the current position to 0. But because the BMP data begins in the middle of the file, you have to use `SEEK_CUR` still. Move the current position back to the beginning of the BMP data:

```
fseek(file, -sizeof(struct BMPHeader) - 4, SEEK_CUR);
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying, but this code may be useful. It creates a BMP file from an array of `RGBType`, specifying the pixel information, the dpi, and the width and height, so you could use it to determine the header in order to pass the correct data alignment to your `FILE`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct RGBType {
    double r;
    double g;
    double b;
} RGBType;

void savebmp (const char *filename, int w, int h, int dpi, RGBType *data) {
    FILE *f;
    int k = w*h;
    int s = 4*k;
    int filesize = 54 + s;

    double factor = 39.375;
    int m = (int)(factor);

    int ppm = dpi*m;

    unsigned char bmpfileheader[14] = {'B','M', 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 54,0,0,0};
    unsigned char bmpinfoheader[40] = {40,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 1,0,24,0};

    bmpfileheader[ 2] = (unsigned char)(filesize);
    bmpfileheader[ 3] = (unsigned char)(filesize>>8);
    bmpfileheader[ 4] = (unsigned char)(filesize>>16);
    bmpfileheader[ 5] = (unsigned char)(filesize>>24);

    bmpinfoheader[ 4] = (unsigned char)(w);
    bmpinfoheader[ 5] = (unsigned char)(w>>8);
    bmpinfoheader[ 6] = (unsigned char)(w>>16);
    bmpinfoheader[ 7] = (unsigned char)(w>>24);

    bmpinfoheader[ 8] = (unsigned char)(h);
    bmpinfoheader[ 9] = (unsigned char)(h>>8);
    bmpinfoheader[10] = (unsigned char)(h>>16);
    bmpinfoheader[11] = (unsigned char)(h>>24);

    bmpinfoheader[21] = (unsigned char)(s);
    bmpinfoheader[22] = (unsigned char)(s>>8);
    bmpinfoheader[23] = (unsigned char)(s>>16);
    bmpinfoheader[24] = (unsigned char)(s>>24);

    bmpinfoheader[25] = (unsigned char)(ppm);
    bmpinfoheader[26] = (unsigned char)(ppm>>8);
    bmpinfoheader[27] = (unsigned char)(ppm>>16);
    bmpinfoheader[28] = (unsigned char)(ppm>>24);

    bmpinfoheader[29] = (unsigned char)(ppm);
    bmpinfoheader[30] = (unsigned char)(ppm>>8);
    bmpinfoheader[31] = (unsigned char)(ppm>>16);
    bmpinfoheader[32] = (unsigned char)(ppm>>24);

    f = fopen(filename, "wb");

    fwrite(bmpfileheader,1,14,f);
    fwrite(bmpinfoheader,1,40,f);

    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        RGBType rgb = data[i];

        double red = (data[i].r)*255;
        double green = (data[i].g)*255;
        double blue = (data[i].b)*255;

        unsigned char color[3] = {(int)floor(blue), (int)floor(green), (int)floor(red)};

        fwrite(color,1,3,f);
    }

    fclose(f);

}

int thisone;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int dpi = 72;

    int width = 640;
    int height = 480;
    int n = width*height;

    RGBType *pixels = (RGBType*) malloc(n * sizeof(RGBType));

    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            thisone = y*width + x;

            pixels[thisone].r = 23;
            pixels[thisone].g = 222;
            pixels[thisone].b = 10;
        }
    }

    savebmp("image.bmp",width,height,dpi,pixels);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not sure why this has been downvoted. It doesn't provide an answer, but it may definitely be helpful.